# Unit testing not working in new gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Hi i have created a new gem in which there is a method which reads a json file and prints the data of json file on console. now i want to write unit test for this gem. so i have created a file mivi_test.rb inside test/unit/ directory.

```
mivi_test.rb
require 'active_support'
class MiviTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def test_mivi
     assert_equal "test","test"
  end
end
```

i want to check if the input and outpur is same. soi run this file with `ruby test/unit/mivi_test.rb` it doesnot throw any error but the output is blank. i am expecting it will print on console like `1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors` 
but my output is blank. please help me to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add next:

```
 require "minitest/autorun"
```